# Hay alguna libreria para hacer un servidor en javascript?

Tags: javascript

Existe una librería para javascript que ayude a hacer un servidor online?

Comment: servidor de ... http?, smtp?, pop?, imap?, ftp?, git?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Para trabajar con servidores online, debes usar Javascript en el lado del servidor, el cual es *NodeJS*.

A su vez, [NodeJS](https://nodejs.org/es/) tiene librerias para hacer webs en tiempo real, como [socket.io](https://socket.io/)